# How to get minimum and maximum value of each type in elixir

Tags: elixir

How to get minimum and maximum value of each type in elixir? for example an integer, float and maximum possible length of a string.

I know that in C it's defined in `limits.h` as `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX` and so on. Where the documentation about the limit of those types in elixir?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Elixir (Erlang actually) uses [bignum arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), which is a kind of arithmentic used in computer science where (quoting Wikipedia)

> calculations are performed on numbers whose digits of precision are limited only by the available memory of the host system

There's [a page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) in the Erlang docs which talks about the limits of the Erlang VM (e.g., atoms can have a maximum of 255 characters); as you can see if you give a look at that page, integers limits aren't even mentioned.

Integers in Erlang/Elixir are only limited by the memory available on the system, so there's virtually **no limit** on how large they can be.

For binaries (strings), I will just quote what the page I linked above says:

> In the 32-bit implementation of Erlang, 536870911 bytes is the largest binary that can be constructed or matched using the bit syntax. (In the 64-bit implementation, the maximum size is 2305843009213693951 bytes.) If the limit is exceeded, bit syntax construction will fail with a system_limit exception, while any attempt to match a binary that is too large will fail. This limit is enforced starting with the R11B-4 release; in earlier releases, operations on too large binaries would in general either fail or give incorrect results. In future releases of Erlang/OTP, other operations that create binaries (such as list_to_binary/1) will probably also enforce the same limit.